# Getting two sets of sequential numbers to work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a script that is supposed collect two sets of high and low numbers and incorporate them into a single string:

a_low and a_high
b_low and b_high

I had found a script and tweaked it to generate one set of numbers (a)

```
function gennumlst(){
   var alow = document.getElementById('a_low').value.replace(/\-/g,'');
   var ahigh = document.getElementById('a_high').value.replace(/\-/g,'');
   var blow = document.getElementById('b_low').value.replace(/\-/g,'');
   var bhigh = document.getElementById('b_high').value.replace(/\-/g,'');
   var textout = new Array();
   var len = ahigh - alow;
   sca = Math.abs(alow);
   for (var x = 0; x < len+1; x++){
       textout[x] = a + (x+sca) + b;}}
   textout = textout.join(delimiter);
   document.getElementById('output_box').value = textout;}
```

I'm able to get a1b, a2b... a5b etc. as output.

What I'm looking for is to get a second set of numbers to work like a1b1, a2b1 ....a5b1, a1b2, a1b3...a1b5 etc.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested loops:

```
arrout = [];
for (var a = alow; a <= ahigh; a++) {
    for (var b = blow; b <= bhigh; b++) {
        arrout.push('a'+a+'b'+b);
    }
}
textout = arrout.join(delimiter);
```

This is really basic programming. You need to go back to the books if you need to ask for help with this, since you'll be totally lost in anything really interesting.